# How to get state from multiple children components to parent to handle without using Redux

Tags: react-native, components

I have a parent which encloses three child component in a tab view, the parent also contain a button which handles a POST request after getting all the state from all three child components. How do I retrieve all the states from the three child components back to the parent to handle once the button in the parent is clicked?

I do not wish to use Redux as it is complicated to me even though I have watched multiple videos and learnt through many different sources

Answer (score 0):

You could use redux, save in store and update your parents but if you don't want to use it, you could do something like this :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';

class ParentComponent extends Component {

  state = {
    child1: 0,
    child2: 0,
    child3: 0,
  };

  settingState = (key, val) => {
    this.setState(state => ({
      ...state,
      [key]: val,
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { child1, child2, child3 } = this.state;
    return (
      <View>
        <ChildOne child1={child1} settingState={this.settingState} />
        <ChildTwo child2={child2} settingState={this.settingState} />
        <ChildThree child3={child3} settingState={this.settingState} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Like this you're setting the state from the parent and have access to it any time. You won't be able to access a child's state, as far as i know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use refs to retrive state from child components https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```
constroctor() {
 super()
 this.tab1 = React.createRef()
 this.tab2 = React.createRef()
 this.tab3 = React.createRef()
}

handleSomeAction = () => {
  console.log(this.tab1.current.state)

  // this method require to create method getState = () => this.state in Tab component 
  console.log(this.tab1.current.getState())
}

<Tabs onClick={this.handleSomeAction}>
 <Tab ref={this.tab1}>
 <Tab ref={this.tab2}>
 <Tab ref={this.tab3}>
</Tabs>
```

You can add handler handleSomeAction on your button instead of on Tabs component